# Azure Data Transfer API in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

Is there any way I can get the Data transfer charges using **Azure Python SDK**?

I'm using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-consumption/azure.mgmt.consumption.consumptionmanagementclient?view=azure-python) to fetch my bill details, but I can't find the data transfer charges in this API

Am I going the wrong way? Or is there any other **Azure Python API** which gives the data transfer charges?

Comment: What do you mean "Data transfer charges"?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/
Azure charges for outbound data transfers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the Data transfer charges with Azure Consumption Rest API,  you can use REST API [List Usage Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails). For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list)
[image]

Regarding how to call the APi with python sdk, please refer to the following code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.consumption import ConsumptionManagementClient

tenant_id=
client_id=
client_secret=
credential=ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

consumption_client = ConsumptionManagementClient(
        credential=credential,
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )

consumption_client.usage_details.list(scope='',expand='meterDetails,additionalInfo')
```